# Why can an Alchemist use non-personal formulae?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

On the Alchemist's formula list there are a few that involve magic item generation such as Deathwine and Water of Maddening.

These spells target an object, and not the caster (you) or a target character, so how can they be cast by an alchemist?

Comment: I think the idea is that the extract *is* deathwine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alchemist is not limited to to formulae of spells with those type of targets, it is limited to fomulae in his class list. Most of those formulae  enter into those targeting categories you noted, because, well, the alchemist must drink a extract to activate it, and it would make litle sense otherwise. All extracts work that way, you drink the extract, and the spell effect happens. Some formulae, however, can be hard to associate with this way of work at first glance.

With [deathwine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deathwine), the alchemist drink the extract, and it gives the alchemist a temporary ability. In this particular case, it allows to turn one or more healing potion he can touch into a temporary necromancy amplifier. You can find at least one example of a extract that give a similar ability: [absorbing touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/absorbing-touch).

As for [water of maddening](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/water-of-maddening), it is not as clear (it has not a target to begin with). Maybe it works like [Vomit swarm](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/vomitSwarm.html) or [Trasmute potion to poison](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/transmutePotionToPoison.html), where  the alchemist drinks the extract, then expel the result of the spell from his own body. Or maybe, like the case of deathwine, the alchemist simply gains an ability, upon drinking the extract, that let him to create the water from other substance (the amber dust used as component of the spell, as a example).

As a side note, even if the mechanics of those two spells require some hand waving to match the mechanics of most other formulae (and they are not the unique), their theme fits more than well with the alchemy/ potion creating theme.